# Appending to specific element append text only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have prepended one div inside some div with many others:

```
<div class="content">
<div>sss</div>
<div>aaa</div>
<div>bbb</div>
</div>
```

I added `<div>ddd</div> before sss` with:

```
$('.content').prepend('<div></div>');
```

And when I want to append some new element to new prepended div it add's it as text:

```
$('.content>div')[0].append('<p>ddd</p>');
```

If I remove `[0]` it works but it appends to all divs, I need that `[0]` to find first div.

Comment: `$('.content>div:first').append('<p>ddd</p>');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the first element (that is still a jquery object) you can use `.first()`:

```
$('.content>div').first().append($('<p>ddd</p>'));
```

Note that I also wrapped the `<p>` with `$(...)` to make it a valid html element (and not text).